how should i modify this.$route.query.comment？
The initial number of comments is obtained by passing parameters from another component through routing.This component with a form has the function of deleting comments and can return the total number of comments. I hope that the subsequent form will use the total number of comments returned.
handleClickAuditDetails: debounce(function (orderId,comment) {
this.$router.push({
name: "MomentsDynamicAudit",
query: {orderId: orderId,comment:comment}
})
}, 200),

temp.comment = this.$route.query.comment
this.tableData = \[temp\]
this.tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData))
if(this.$route.query.comment !== 0){
this.getCommentsTableData()
}

async getCommentsTableData() {
//Pagination
this.totalComments = response.data.commentCount;
//I know this code is wrong and there will be no change at all unless the value of the 
 route parameter changes.
this.$route.query.comment=response.data.commentCount;
}

I hope that after the comments are deleted, the table will automatically update the total number, instead of always using the value of the parameter passed by the route.

Did you try to make router.push call with the exact comment value you need? It's possible that you try to maintain app state through route params when you need global state like a store

Do you want me to use Vuex's state to display the number of comments in the second component table?

I did not attempt to use Vuex to solve this problem, as it is only a small parameter that cannot be used elsewhere

I can't recommend this because it's unknown what happens in your app and how "comment" is used. But it's possible that this could be the case. It's not vuex specifically but some kind of state in general, e.g parent component state that isn't unmounted
